# Is GaAs (100) surface polar?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, crystals

I have a question on the GaAs surfaces. Depending on the crystal orientation, GaAs could be polar or non-polar. For example (111)B surfaces are terminated by the As atoms, whereas A surface is Ga-terminated. (110) surfaces are non-polar, meaning both As and Ga can bond to this surface. I am wondering about the (100) surfaces. When I check the cubic structure, it seems to me that it might have some polarity. Is this the case? If so, why don't wafer providers specify when selling them?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the GaAs (100) surfaces are polar, and can be terminated either at As or at Ga layer. However, (100) GaAs possesses a rich variety of surface reconstructions, most of which would strongly reduce surface polarity (see e.g. [*Surface reconstructions on GaAs(001)* by Akihiro Ohtake](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167572908000198)). With regards to wafers, usually polarity of GaAs (100) is not specified, which likely means that wafer manufactures have no control over the surface in the fabrication.